# How can I ask the JVM if a file has been marked for deletion via File.deleteOnExit()?

Tags: java, junit, jvm, delete-file

I have Java code that marks files for deletion via `File.deleteOnExit()`.  It works fine.  I have a JUnit test setup to check if these files have been deleted.  Of course this check fails because the unit test JVM has not terminated yet when the check is performed.

Is there a way a ask if these files are slated for deletion by the JVM?

Comment: I don't know much about `JUnit` test, but can't you use `File f = new File("filePath"); f.exists();`?

Comment: I was already doing that, unfortunately.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to call File.deleteOnExit() frequently if you are using a long running application server, as it could be a cause OutOfMemoryException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Man, if I had just waited a few moments ...

This works:

```
Field field = Class.forName("java.io.DeleteOnExitHook").getDeclaredField("files");
field.setAccessible(true);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
LinkedHashSet<String> files = (LinkedHashSet<String>)field.get(null);
```

I can then check the set and see if my files are contained therein.

Comment: Answering your own question is a perfectly acceptable practice on SO.